# how to check system date is wrong in cordova android application

Tags: android, cordova, date, time

I have a cordova android application. It works online and offline mode. How can I check the system date-time is correct or not? In online method I can check with server date-time but any other way for that? in offline how I can check? 
I tried with Geo-location time, still it gives me back the system date-time.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to determine the correct local time of the device without network access is by using the **GPS** time. You cannot magically get the proper time without any connection to the outside world, it's like trying to accurately set a clock in the middle of a cloudy night.

Comment: Unfortunately GPS gives device time itself

Comment: Are you sure you have implemented it correctly? Is the GPS working? Try the [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) app and check what time is the GPS returning, if it's the correct time then your plugin implementation is wrong.